# How to prevent a new project from being linked to the primary project automatically?

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, I'd like that every new project will not be linked to the primary project automatically when I create it.
Is there a way to do it properly?

When a new project is created and attached to the current window, it is automatically linked to the primary project:

[image: Screenshot new project.]

Comment: I tried several times to find a way of customizing this behavior in the IDE when opening several projects in the same window but it simply cannot be done. There is no such feature in PyCharm and the only chance would be requesting the developers to implement it by posting a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues.

Comment: Hello, yes thanks but since there is no solution right now I won't "accept" this answer. I upvoted your answer and thanks for information. Best,

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do it properly?

The simple answer is: No, this can't be done currently.

If you select *"Open projects in the same window"* and "Attach", see [Open multiple projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html#c23168a7). PyCharm's default behavior is linking the new projects as dependencies of the primary project.

There is no setting in the IDE to change this default behavior, if you want to remove the dependencies you'll have to do it manually in `File` `>` `Project` `>` `Project Dependencies` `>` `Project depends on these projects`.

---

---

You can customize the "Project opening policy" at `Appearance and Behavior` `>` `System Settings` `>` `Project` but that only changes the dialogue, not the automatic setting of the dependency if opening in the same window.