# Does Pycharm limit the number of projects it can hold?

Tags: python, pycharm

I was looking through my pycharm projects, and noticed that 2 are not there, looked through all my IDE versions, not there. now I am 100%sure that I did the projects, so my question is does pycharm have a set limit of projects it can hold? I have noticed that when I tried to create a new project with the amount of projects I already have, that pycharm appeared slow to load the new project window, or sometimes did not load at all, I had to create the project several times for it to register.

Hope yall can answer this

Comment: There are support forums at JetBrains specifically for PyCharm.

Comment: do u mean you can't find your project in the recent projects ?  or you can't find the project at all?

Comment: For the slow indexing see [PyCharm 4.0.5 hangs on 'scanning files to index' background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030682). Having multiple project in the same window is explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67293615).

Comment: @Amir Saadallah I can't find the projects when I go to 'open recent' and look through the list, for example:I REMEMBER CLEARLY that I did a 'rock paper scissors' program a few weeks back, I look through my list, and it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

The slow performance may be due to numerous tasks hogging CPU/memory resources or perhaps PyCharm memory heap size.  You can read more from about adjusting memory heap size here:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/increasing-memory-heap.html

As for missing projects, perhaps you saved them in a different directory by mistake?

It's relatively easy to make that mistake when first setting up a project.

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-empty-project.html